# Need longer line behind dishwasher

Tags: wiring, dishwasher

Can I pig tail off a #14 wire, to short when I pull out dishwasher, and tie in a #12 wire to make line longer.?

Comment: Your description is a bit confusing.  You're not limited on the number of characters you're allowed to use here, so don't be afraid to give a good description of your problem.   The more detailed you are, the more accurate answer you'll get.

Comment: It sounds as if you have an odd situation. Is the short wire have a Rec./Plug?

Answer (score 1):

You can make wire connections in approved accessible junction boxes. Using 12AWG wire is not necessary if the circuit is protected by a 15A breaker -- 14AWG will do.